# Python3: get current window name?

Tags: python, linux, x11

I want to develop a script that would dump me some statistics over the application usage on my machine. The script should run in background, get events when user switches active windows, and dump information over apps time usage.

What documentation should I refer for that? I have no idea about X11 programming, and I have little idea about GUI toolkits on Linux, and how do they work. Most solutions that I've found on the google tend to use wmctrl or xprop, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the best way to approach this problem is by using your Desktop Environment's plugin system--if it has one.

[Gnome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions)

[KDE](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/DeveloperGuide)

All of the major DE's should have Python bindings.
Good luck!